# Connection in .NET

Tags: .net

I got

> `System.Data.Datarow.Datarow(System.Data.Datarowbuilder)` is inaccessible due to its protection
>   level.

while connecting to SQL-Server. What does it mean?

Comment: Is it a compile-time error? Could you post some relevant code snippet?

Comment: Posting a little bit of your coding where the error happens will help everyone to check what is wrong :)

Answer (score 3):

Difficult to say without some code, but are you doing something like `new DataRow` in your code? If so then that's probably the problem, the constructor is not `public` so you'd have to create your `DataRow`s in some other way (for example by calling `DataTable.NewRow` if you're using a `DataTable`).